# How to find most optimal match between data points given the similarity matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, graph, theory, similarity

I am stuck on a very simple problem but more I try to solve it the harder it becomes. Or maybe there is no better solution than O(N^2). The problem is simple. I have N data points in first set and M data points in second. I have a NxM similarity matrix A such that A[i, j] (range is between 0 and 1) gives score about similarity of Ni and Mj data-points.

I want to find out which the points from first set match the best in the second. i.e the output is list with N elements each one corresponding to unique indices of M set which they match the most.

I am using numpy. I sort matrix on second axis but the issue is argsort will not give me unqiue indices. And with indices logic it becomes really confusing.

Comment: Without assumptions on how `A` is built, you need to read the whole matrix which take `O(N M)` time (just with an `np.argmin`).

Answer (score 1):

`np.argmax(A, axis=1)` does exactly what you describe (assuming that 1 means most similar).

Comment: Yes but I need 1-1 match not repeating ones. An example would be given a matrix:

0.5 0.1 0.0 |

0.1 0.2 0.1 |

0.0 0.9 0.3 |

the argmax will give 0, 1, 1. Matching second and third to same object. Even using argsort and picking the indices I haven't selected before would give 0, 1, 2 while the ideal is 0, 2, 1 because it yields maximum sum.

Comment: I found the solution. You can use np.unravel_index along with argsort to get sorted indices pairs with max score. Traversing in descending order and selecting pairs with best match can lead to solution. You will also need two sets to keep track of removed indices and not pick pairs which have any index from removed sets.